# Postgres binary replication: Standby takes a long time to start

Tags: postgresql

I am using the Postgres binary replication tutorial, and have rsynced all the data files from my master to standby

```
rsync -av --exclude pg_xlog --exclude postgresql.conf data/* 192.168.0.2:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

Afterwards, I'm starting my standby first, and see this in the logs:
FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: could not connect to server: Connection refused

According to the tutorial, this should be fine as I haven't started the master yet.

However when I try to connect to the standby, I get this error msg even after waiting for a few mins:

```
psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
```

My database is 600GB big, is it normal for the standby database to start after I'm done initially copying all the data files over? Or is something seriously wrong? How long does it normally take?

Comment: How many WAL segments accumulated during the rsync from master to slave? If there were lots, then yes, a delayed startup time is normal (or if you have slow disks it will take longer).  A few minutes is not out of the question, but if it is taking tens of minutes or hours then there could be something else going on.

Comment: Look at your server logs, the activity will be logged here. Also you didn't make it explicit that it's a hot standby slave. if it's a warm standby, it's normal that it stays in "starting up" mode until failover.